# Swift custom bubble view component

Tags: ios, swift, charts, uikit

I need to create a component capable of displaying the progress of many runners in the form of a bubble. I have tried to do it with the Charts library which is great but I have not achieved much.

This is the code:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.configureChart(raceChartData: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], raceDistance: 10)
}

func configureChart(raceChartData: [Int], raceDistance: Double) {
    chartView.chartDescription.enabled = false
    chartView.dragEnabled = false
    chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
    chartView.xAxis.enabled = true
    //chartView.maxVisibleCount = 0
    chartView.autoScaleMinMaxEnabled = false
    chartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
    chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    chartView.legend.enabled = false
    chartView.legend.drawInside = false
    chartView.setScaleEnabled(false)
    let xAxis: XAxis = chartView.xAxis
    xAxis.axisLineColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4823529412, blue: 0.1450980392, alpha: 1).withAlphaComponent(0.1)
    xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    xAxis.gridColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4823529412, blue: 0.1450980392, alpha: 1).withAlphaComponent(0.3)
    //xAxis.axisMinimum = 1
    //xAxis.axisMaximum = 10

    var calculatedChartDistance = 0.0

    if raceChartData.count != 0 {
        var chartdistanceArray = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        if activeRaceFormat == "SPDWRK" {
            calculatedChartDistance = raceDistance
        } else {
            chartView.xAxis.centeredEntries = [0, 0.5, 0.4]
            chartView.xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = true
            calculatedChartDistance = raceDistance
        }

        for i in 0...9 {
            chartdistanceArray[i] = calculatedChartDistance * Double((i + 1))
        }

        let yVals1 = [
            BubbleChartDataEntry(x: chartdistanceArray[0], y: 0, size: CGFloat(raceChartData[0])),
            BubbleChartDataEntry(x: chartdistanceArray[1], y: 0, size: CGFloat(raceChartData[1])),
            BubbleChartDataEntry(x: chartdistanceArray[2], y: 0, size: CGFloat(raceChartData[2])),
            BubbleChartDataEntry(x: chartdistanceArray[3], y: 0, size: CGFloat(raceChartData[3])),
            BubbleChartDataEntry(x: chartdistanceArray[4], y: 0, size: CGFloat(raceChartData[4])),
            BubbleChartDataEntry(x: chartdistanceArray[5], y: 0, size: CGFloat(raceChartData[5])),
            BubbleChartDataEntry(x: chartdistanceArray[6], y: 0, size: CGFloat(raceChartData[6])),
            BubbleChartDataEntry(x: chartdistanceArray[7], y: 0, size: CGFloat(raceChartData[7])),
            BubbleChartDataEntry(x: chartdistanceArray[8], y: 0, size: CGFloat(raceChartData[8])),
            BubbleChartDataEntry(x: chartdistanceArray[9], y: 0, size: CGFloat(raceChartData[9]))
        ]

        let set1 = BubbleChartDataSet(entries: yVals1)
        set1.drawIconsEnabled = false
        set1.setColor(ChartColorTemplates.colorful()[1], alpha: 0.5)
        set1.drawValuesEnabled = true
        set1.normalizeSizeEnabled = false

        let data = [set1] as BubbleChartData
        data.setDrawValues(true)
        data.setValueFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 7)!)
        data.setHighlightCircleWidth(0.5)
        chartView.data = data
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Here is the real component I need to create:

[image]

Suppose you have to run 10 KM, the current market line and the bubble with avatar are you (the app user) and the distance you have running. The other bubbles is the amount of people near one from other and their distance. All the data comes from socket (backend) and I need to display in that form. Any idea of how I can do this?, I'm thinking in do a component from scratch (based on UIView) but I don't know if this is a good plan at all.

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you just not know how to draw using Core Graphics?

Comment: I know a bit how to draw, but I have the question if this can be achieved with libraries like Charts or if I need to do it from scratch @matt

Comment: I'm sure drawing it yourself is the only way to get the flexibility you need. It's what I'd do. It looks quite straightforward actually.

Comment: you can achieve it with bubble chart, not the 100% same as like but round about 80 to 85% same as above

Comment: https://github.com/AAChartModel/AAChartKit-Swift

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII I'm trying just now with that library.

Comment: its better to download the demo also

Comment: @Wo_0NDeRᵀᴹ - you will almost ***certainly*** have trouble getting your "goal" with some type of chart library... should be fairly straight-forward to do this with shape layers or overriding draw. Much easier to offer you help, though, if you provide some realistic data. The  sample code you posted will NOT be able to produce the "real component" image you show.

Comment: @DonMag i have done this. In few minutes I will post the code. Let me finish work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended done this so far:

```swift
//
//  DiyBubbleChartView.swift
//  Test Charts
//
//  Created by Fidel Hernández Salazar on 5/29/23.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

// Una clase para representar un gráfico de burbujas con varios corredores
class DiyBubbleChartView: UIView {

    // Un arreglo para almacenar los corredores
    var currentRunners: [Runner] = []

    // Una constante para la distancia total a recorrer
    let totalDistance = 100.0

    // Un método para actualizar corredores en el gráfico
    func updateRunners(_ runners: [Runner]) {
        self.currentRunners.removeAll()
        self.currentRunners = runners
        self.setNeedsDisplay() // Llama al método draw para actualizar el gráfico
    }

    // Un método para agregar un corredor al gráfico
    func addRunner(_ runner: Runner) {
        self.currentRunners.append(runner)
        self.setNeedsDisplay() // Llama al método draw para actualizar el gráfico
    }

    // Un método para dibujar el gráfico de burbujas
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        // Obtiene el contexto gráfico actual
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        self.drawGradientBackground()
        self.drawGridLines()

        // Define el color y el ancho de las líneas
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(0.1)

//        // Dibuja una línea horizontal para representar la distancia total
//        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: bounds.height / 2))
//        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - 10, y: bounds.height / 2))
//        context.strokePath()

//        // Dibuja una etiqueta con la distancia total
//        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: bounds.width - 50, y: bounds.height / 2 - 20, width: 40, height: 20))
//        label.text = "\(totalDistance)"
//        label.textColor = .black
//        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
//        addSubview(label)

        // Agrupa los corredores que están juntos en un diccionario con la distancia como clave y el número de corredores como valor
        var groups: [Double: Int] = [:]

        for runner in currentRunners {
            groups[runner.distance, default: 0] += 1
        }

        // Para cada grupo de corredores, dibuja una burbuja con un radio proporcional al número de corredores y una posición proporcional a la distancia
        for (distance, count) in groups {
            var radius = CGFloat(count) // El radio de la burbuja es 5 veces el número de corredores

            // Verifica si el radio es mayor que la mitad de la altura de la vista
            if radius > (bounds.height / 2) - 20.0 {
                // Si lo es, reduce el radio a ese valor (20.0 es el margin)
                radius = (bounds.height / 2) - 20.0
            }

            var x = 10 + CGFloat(distance / totalDistance) * (bounds.width - 20) // La posición x de la burbuja es proporcional a la distancia recorrida
            let y = bounds.height / 2 // La posición y de la burbuja es la mitad de la altura del gráfico

            // Verifica si la posición x más el radio es mayor que el ancho de la vista
            if x + radius > bounds.width {
                // Si lo es, resta la diferencia al valor de x para mover la burbuja hacia la izquierda
                x -= (x + radius) - bounds.width
            }

            // Dibuja un círculo con el centro y el radio dados
            // Establece el color de relleno del contexto gráfico
            context.setFillColor(UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor)
            context.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true)
            context.fillPath()
            context.strokePath()

//            // Dibuja una etiqueta con el número de corredores dentro de la burbuja
//            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x - radius, y: y - radius, width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2))
//            label.text = "\(count)"
//            label.textColor = .black
//            label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 7)! // .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
//            label.textAlignment = .center
//            addSubview(label)
        }

        self.drawBubbleWithUserAvatar(withGroups: groups)
    }

    // Crea una instancia de CAGradientLayer y le asigna un tamaño igual al de la vista
    func drawGradientBackground() {

        // Remover todas las sublayers para evitar problemas
        self.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

        // Define los colores para el degradado
        let firstColor = UIColor(named: "firstColor")!.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        let secondColor = UIColor(named: "secondColor")!.withAlphaComponent(0.3)

        // Define los colores del degradado como un arreglo de CGColor
        gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]

        // Define los puntos de inicio y fin del degradado como CGPoint
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)

        // Agrega el degradado como una subcapa de la vista
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }

    // Dibuja las lineas horizontales de la grafica
    func drawGridLines() {
        // Obtiene el contexto gráfico actual
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        let lineColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4823529412, blue: 0.1450980392, alpha: 1).withAlphaComponent(0.3)

        // Define una constante para la distancia entre las líneas
        let lineSpacing = 32.0

        context.setStrokeColor(lineColor.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(1.0)

        // Define una constante para el número de líneas a dibujar
        let numberOfLines = Int((bounds.width - 20) / lineSpacing)

        // Para cada línea, calcula su posición x y dibuja una línea vertical desde el borde superior hasta el borde inferior de la vista
        for i in 0...numberOfLines {
            let x = 10 + CGFloat(i) * lineSpacing // La posición x de la línea es igual al margen izquierdo más el espaciado multiplicado por el índice de la línea
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: 0)) // Mueve el punto inicial al borde superior de la vista
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: bounds.height)) // Agrega una línea al borde inferior de la vista
            context.strokePath() // Dibuja la línea
        }
    }

    func drawBubbleWithUserAvatar(withGroups: [Double: Int]) {
        // Define una constante con el nombre del corredor principal
        let mainRunnerName = "User 1"

        // Obtiene la distancia recorrida por el corredor principal
        let mainRunnerDistance = currentRunners.first(where: { $0.name == mainRunnerName })!.distance

        // Obtiene el número de corredores en el mismo grupo que el corredor principal
        let mainRunnerCount = withGroups[mainRunnerDistance]!

        // Calcula el radio y la posición x de la burbuja del corredor principal usando las mismas fórmulas que antes
        let mainRunnerRadius = CGFloat(mainRunnerCount * 10)
        let mainRunnerX = 10 + CGFloat(mainRunnerDistance / totalDistance) * (bounds.width - 20)

        // Crea una instancia de UIImageView con una imagen de prueba (puedes cambiarla por la imagen real del perfil del usuario)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "user-avatar"))

        // Calcula el radio de la imagen como el mismo que el de la burbuja del usuario
        var imageRadius = mainRunnerRadius

        // Verifica si el radio es mayor que la mitad de la altura de la vista
        if imageRadius > (bounds.height / 2) - 20.0 {
            // Si lo es, reduce el tamaño de la imagen a ese valor
            imageRadius = (bounds.height / 2) - 20.0
        }

//        // Le asigna un tamaño y una posición iguales a los de la burbuja del corredor principal
//        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: mainRunnerX - mainRunnerRadius, y: bounds.height / 2 - mainRunnerRadius, width: mainRunnerRadius * 2, height: mainRunnerRadius * 2)

        // Le asigna un tamaño y una posición iguales a los de la burbuja del usuario
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: mainRunnerX - imageRadius, y: bounds.height / 2 - imageRadius, width: imageRadius * 2, height: imageRadius * 2)

        // Le da una forma circular recortando las esquinas
        //imageView.layer.cornerRadius = mainRunnerRadius
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageRadius
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        // Agrega la imagen como una subvista de la vista
        addSubview(imageView)

        // Obtiene el contexto gráfico actual
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.init(named: "firstColor")!.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(1.0)

        // Calcula las posiciones y del inicio y fin de la línea como el borde superior e inferior de la vista principal
        let startY = 0.0
        let endY = bounds.height

        // Dibuja una línea vertical con los puntos dados
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: mainRunnerX, y: startY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: mainRunnerX, y: endY))
        context.strokePath()

        /// .......

        // Crea una instancia de CALayer y le asigna un tamaño y una posición que cubran el área deseada
        let backgroundLayer = CALayer()
        backgroundLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mainRunnerX, height: bounds.height)

        // Define el color del fondo como un CGColor
        backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "secondColor")!.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor

        // Agrega el fondo como una subcapa de la vista
        self.layer.insertSublayer(backgroundLayer, at: 1)
    }
}
```

To test, in some view controller:

```swift
let chart = DiyBubbleChartView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 110))
var runners: [Runner] = []

var distances = [Double]()

// Rellenar las distancias posibles desde 1 hasta 100
for i in 1...100 {
    distances.append(Double(i))
}

for i in 1...100 {
    self.runners.append(Runner(name: "User \(i)", distance:   distances.randomElement() ?? 1.0, isUser: false))
}

self.updateBubbleView(withRunners: self.runners)
```

And the updateBubbleView func

```swift
func updateBubbleView(withRunners: [Runner]) {
    // Crea una instancia del gráfico de burbujas y le agrega algunos corredores de prueba
    self.chart.updateRunners(withRunners)
}
```